# Where is /etc/default/docker file on Amazon Linux EC2 server?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine, amazon-linux

I am trying docker examples and wanted to set the DOCKER_OPTS, but not able to find /etc/default/docker on amazon linux machine. Where to look for it?

Comment: Try launching a ec2 with amazon ecs-optimized-ami (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html) which comes with docker installed.

Comment: Docker is not installed on base ec2 servers. Try running `which docker` to check if docker is installed or not.

Answer (score 4):

In Amazon linux (CentOS,Fedora,RedHat etc), you can find it in  `/etc/sysconfig/docker`

You need to restart docker service once you update that file.

If you didn't find it, check if docker is installed in that machine. Its recommended to use ecs-optimized-ami for running docker containers.

More details: [ECS Optimized AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html)

Comment: indeed there is file /etc/sysconfig/docker. But from the Docker documentation, it looks like they are suggesting new way by using /etc/docker/daemon.json. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Latest docker versions use `/etc/docker/daemon.json` for changing the daemon options. I would suggest to use this file instead of environment variables. Look at the below docker documentation for more details

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file

Comment: That entirely depends if the distro uses upstart or systemd and if docker was packaged in a cusom way for that distro.

Comment: @Grimmy,

That's not the case with latest version. I check the systemctl of docker on my system it has `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://`. If I update/create `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to below content

{
 "insecure-registries": ["testme.com:8000"]
}

restart docker and check `docker info` it shows testme.com in output. So the file is loaded if it exists, even if the startup script doesn't define the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Adding DOCKER_OPTS to `/etc/sysconfig/docker` will not work in Amazon Linux 2.

You will see this when watching the logs.

```
journalctl -u docker.service

Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'DOCKER_OPTS=
Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]:     --cluster-advertise=eth0:2375
Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]:     --cluster-store=consul://consul:8500
Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]:     --host tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]:     --host unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]:     --log-driver=gelf
Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]:     --log-opt gelf-address=udp://127.0.0.1:1513
Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]:     --log-opt tag=docker
Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]:     --userland-proxy=false
Jan 17 08:11:07 portal-staging-new systemd[1]: ': /etc/sysconfig/docker
```

So you will need to add the config to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.